# Extracting info from logs with timestamp

Tags: python, logging, timestamp

I am reading console output from one of our hardware modules, extracting some info via python script using regex, and writing that info to a file. The info does get extracted successfully but I would like write the timestamp(current) as well before each line. Is there a way to do that? My console output doesn't display any time stamp.

```
# Regex used to match relevant loglines
line_regex = re.compile(r".*<my_string_1>.*$")
line_regex1 = re.compile(r".*<my_string>.*$")

# Output file, where the matched loglines will be copied to
output_filename = os.path.normpath("parsed_lines.log")
# Overwrites the file, ensure we're starting out with a blank file
with open(output_filename, "w") as out_file:
    out_file.write("")
while 1:
# Open output file in 'append' mode
  with open(output_filename, "a") as out_file:
    # Open input file in 'read' mode
      with open("test_log.txt", "r") as in_file:
        # Loop over each log line
          for line in in_file:
            # If log line matches our regex, print to console, and output file
              if ((line_regex.search(line)) or (line_regex1.search(line))):
                  print (line)
                  sleep (0.5)
                  out_file.write(line)
```

actual result:

ABC054: dur=354 xfer=320 wait=0 proc=152 total=152 { file: '../csi/range-1548454834692-0000016887176adb-00112AAA0054-00112AAA0050.json' }

TOTAL: 1

expected result :

HH:MM:SS  ABC054: dur=354 xfer=320 wait=0 proc=152 total=152 { file: '../csi/range-1548454834692-0000016887176adb-00112AAA0054-00112AAA0050.json' }

HH:MM:SS  TOTAL: 1

I was able to get it work by replacing

```
out_file.write(line)
```

with

```
out_file.write(line.replace("\n", " [%s]\n" % str(datetime.datetime.now()))).
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the time with

```
import time

time.time()
```

Or if you want date and time

```
import datetime

datetime.datetime.now()
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm using this:

```
import time

def tprint(*args, **kwargs):
    print(time.strftime("%H:%M:%S"), *args, **kwargs)

tprint("hello")
tprint("world")
```

Maybe the module logging has a similar feature?